# No MongoDB versions have been made available for use in your deployment. OPS manager mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

Ive setup OPS manager in AWS EC2 using the tutorial mentioned

```
https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/
```

When done and when I tried to create a new **Deployment**

```
No MongoDB versions have been made available for use in your deployment. At least one MongoDB version must be made available before any changes to your Deployment can be made using Automation.
```

This is the error I got . How to resolve this now

Comment: Pass Database array as a props to the component ?

Comment: I just want the array to pass to other class and use it there I didn't ask for using them as props. It may not be the solution for the question

Comment: Very less detail regarding what you are using. 

there are multiple ways to acheive this. 
are you using redux ? or any other state management library? 
If not, you might need React COntext to put that data inside a context and consume in different components.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire approach of trying to get data in function like this and then export it for use in another class is not really the React way and won't work because React won't know when the array changed. You should use something like https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html to fetch data that you want to render inside the component you want to render it. If you want to cache the result globally for multiple components then you should look at something like Redux with Redux-Thunk.

The following is an example of my first suggestion which can be placed inside your render function:

```
const [db, setDb] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    let Database = [];
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/someRoute')
        .then((response) => {
            let jsonStr = response.json();
            jsonStr.then((result) => {
                //console.log(result);                  
                for (let i in result) {
                    let Details = {
                        title: [],

                    };
                    Details.title = result[i].title;

                    Database.push(Details);
                }
            })
        })

    setDb(Database);
});
```

You will also need to add the following imports:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: After Adding that in the render what is the next step

Comment: Your array will be available in the "db" variable (if your fetch code works) and then you can display it in whatever way you want. The array will just be empty until the fetch completes.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap youp fetch inside a Promise

```
fetchD = () => {
    let Database = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              fetch('http://localhost:3000/someRoute')
        .then((response) => {
            let jsonStr = response.json();
            jsonStr.then((result) => {
                //console.log(result);                  
                for (let i in result) {
                    let Details = {
                        title: [],

                    };
                    Details.title = result[i].title;

                    Database.push(Details);
                    resolve(Database);
                }
            })
        });
    })
};
```

now in your component

```
import fetchD from './ the _place_you_exported';

/*
  other code
*/

    someMethod() {
       fetchD().then(data => {
           // do something with the data
           // here data will be the same value what you resolved in this case it will be the Database array
       })
    }
```